# Strange Behavior Binding DataContext & IsEnabled-Property on UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

i have a strange behavior of binding `DataContext` & `IsEnabled` Property of a UserControl.

In my page, I use a UserControl like this:

```
<httpsPort:HttpsPort DataContext="{Binding Path=Https}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentServiceState, Converter={StaticResource ServiceStateIsConfigableConverter}}" />
```

And a Button such as this:

```
<Button Content="start service"
    IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentServiceState, Converter={StaticResource ServiceStateIsConfigableConverter}}"
    Command="{Binding CmdConfigureService}" [...] />
```

explanation:

the converter converts the currentServiceState-Enum to bool. My Button behaves as I expect it (En/DisAbled).

problem: my button is correctly en/disabled, but the controls in my usercontrol are not.

The DataContext (HTTPS) is actually not null:

```
private HttpsPortViewModel _https;
    public HttpsPortViewModel Https
    {
        get
        {
            if (_https == null)
            {
                _https = new HttpsPortViewModel();
            }
            return _https;
        }
        set
        {
            _https = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Https);
        }
    }
```

i have tried to use FallbackValue=False on my UserControls Binding, but then UserControl is even Disabled...

Can anybody explain these behavior?
Thanks a lot.

**Update:**

My Workaround:

```
<Grid IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentServiceState, Converter={StaticResource ServiceStateIsConfigableConverter}}">
    <httpsPort:HttpsPort DataContext="{Binding Path=Https}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You never actually stated your problem. Please do so.

Comment: hi daniel, the problem is, that the usercontrol is not en/disabled like the button is.

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to bind the DataContext property. Why do you do that for the usercontrol? It seems to work for the button without it.

Comment: My UserControl has a ViewModel too (MVVM), and the parent viewModel uses attributes from UserControlViewModel.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand correctly, but binding the datacontext property would result in the datacontext to be set permanently once after another. Instead use an appropriate BindingPath. E.g. Https.CurrentServiceState

Answer (score 0):

You should not be binding your own `DataContext`. Any binding operation USES the `DataContext`, so binding your `DataContext` is a circular operation. Even if this worked there is no guarantee in what order your bindings are created, so your `IsEnabled` property could be bound before your `DataContext` was bound to its new value.

Instead you should specificy the full path for properties. eg:

```
<httpsPort:HttpsPort IsEnabled="{Binding Https.CurrentServiceState, Converter={StaticResource ServiceStateIsConfigableConverter}}" />
```

Comment: okay, i understand the problem of binding order. the main idea was to outsource a group of controls as an usercontrol. these groupbox is used in two (page)ViewModels. These ViewModels needs access to the UserControlViewModel (get port & selected certificate) but the (page)viewmodels should be able to disabled the usercontrol (e.g. service is running). perhaps, my "solution" not the best way... note the CurrentServiceState is not an attribtue of https, its an attribute of parent view model (page)

Comment: Then just expose your UserControlViewModel from each PageViewModel. The DataContext remains pointing to a PageViewModel, and you can bind your user control properties with full paths as in my answer.